# Macro to place a vlookup formula in the same cell in only in select sheet array

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm attempting to create a macro that places a vlookup formula in the same cell but only for a select sheet range (Basically every sheet except the first two)  Here's my code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RenameTest()
For Each aSheet.Array In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
aSheet.Array = Sheets(Array("Facility Varian-HM_OH_477417 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_217368 -") _
    ).Select
aSheet.Activate
If aSheet.Name <> "Sheet87" Then
    Dim lookupvalue As String
    Dim formulavalue As String
    lookupvalue = Cells(1, 2).Value
    formulavalue = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & ",'Sheet87'!A2:I200;3;FALSE)"
    Cells(1, 4).FormulaLocal = formulavalue
End If

Next aSheet

End Sub
```

When running the code I get the following error: Compile error:  Variable not defined.  Any insight on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is aSheet defined somewhere? I don't see a Dim before first use on line 3.  Assuming that's not the problem, can you tell us which line the debugger stops on?

Comment: With the line `Option Explicit` at the top of your code you have to declare all variables with an `Dim` statement. For example `Dim aSheet As Worksheet`. But before we can help you further you need to clarify some things in the code: is the lookup value to be taken from each sheet where the VLookup formula is places or from one central sheet? What is the fourth line for? Is this where you are naming the two sheets which should not get included? If so, what is the next excemption with `If aSheet.Name <> "Sheet87" Then`?

Comment: @Ralph Sheet87 is the sheet where the lookup actually happens.  The thing is I have a massive workbook where I want to insert the formula on each sheet in A4 based on the lookup value in A2.  The whole goal was than using a indirect VBA to change the name on all tabs because the way the worksheet tab names come are hard to cipher through

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps

```
On Error Resume Next    
formulavalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(" & lookupvalue & ",'Sheet87'!A2:I200;3;FALSE)
Cells(1, 4).Value = formulavalue
```